# High lighting row is not working as expected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which binds master and child data, when there is no data in child I would like to highlight the entire tr in green it is working partially with the code I have written

```js
$("#Main tbody>tr").each(function() {
  var textval = $(this).find($("[id$='_rowCount']")).text();

  if (parseInt(textval) === 0) {
    $(this).addClass("alert-success");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("alert-success");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Main" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="search-table-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <strong>
    <span id="Main_ctl02_Label4" class="left-loated">Test</span>
   </strong>
            <span id="Main_ctl02_rowCount" class="rowStyle hidden">1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Main_ctl02_Child" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1">Data exists</td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="search-table-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <strong>
       <span id="Main_ctl03_Label4" class="leftfloated">Test1</span>
            </strong>
            <span id="Main_ctl03_rowCount" class="rowStyle hidden">0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Main_ctl03_Child" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="6">No Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="search-table-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <strong>
   <span id="Main_ctl03_Label4" class="left-floated">Test2</span>
            </strong>
            <span id="Main_ctl03_rowCount" class="rowStyle hidden">0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Main_ctl03_Child" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="6">No Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you see the second tr is highlighted in green where as the 3rd one is not fully so can some one help me, I am having rowcount where it shows the number based on that I am adding the class.

**My guess is due to default class of table `table table-striped table-bordered`** but I would like to keep this and apply the style as required

Comment: That `parseInt` is suspicious!

Comment: That is working fine when I remove this `table-striped` I am getting as expected but I would like to know is there way to over ride

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS rules override it because of [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity)

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}


.alert-success {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
```

The specificity is greater so it overrides your one.

Comment: Is there a way can I over write this with in my function where I am performing each

Comment: Can you just make a selector that has a higher specificity?

Comment: `.table-striped>tbody>tr.alert-success:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #dff0d8; }`

Comment: Can I specify that in my script?